# Publish script with huge tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a backup of specific tables within SQL but when publishing the script with data included the script is just too big. It has been running now for more that an hour and the script size is already more than a terabyte. Even executing a script this big would be impossible.

I have recreated backups for these tables within SQL but it is just simply too big and I do not have enough space on my DB directory.

Does anyone have any advice on how to make backups of these tables?

```
Table 1 : 56,370,203 records
Table 2 : 35,528,469 records
Table 3 :  7,965,568 records
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SQL Server, I assume?  What version of SQL Server?

Comment: What is the purpose of this backup?  Why not just Backup the whole database?

Comment: Hi Barry, I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I only want to update specific table within the database. This is live data so making a backup of the entire database and if needed, restoring, would make me lose all data that was created while I was busy.

Comment: If it's live, what would prevent you from losing updates/inserts to the tables you're trying to back up?  Since this is production, I'd suggest taking your application down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you only want to preserve that state of certain tables and then restore them later, this is what I would do:

1) Make another database [TableBackup].

2) To backup the tables, do this for each table:

> ```
> USE [TableBackup]
> GO
> IF OBJECT_ID('<<yourTable>>') IS NOT NULL  DROP <<yourTable>>;
> SELECT * INTO <<yourTable>> FROM <<yourDB>>.dbo.<<yourTable>>;
> GO
> ```

3) To restore the tables, do this for each table:

> ```
> USE [<<yourDB>>]
> GO
> TRUNCATE <<yourTable>>;
> INSERT INTO <<yourTable>> FROM [TableBackup].dbo.<<yourTable>>;
> GO
> ```

Untested.  You may have to adjust this for Foreign Keys and/or Identity columns on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create another database, copy the data you are interested into that DB (I suppose it depends on the row size as to how feasible this is)

Once you've copied the data into another DB, you can take a backup of that on it's own. At least then you don't need to take a full backup of the whole db!

After you are done you can empty the copy db and free up some server space.

Alternatively, get yourself a really big drive...

Comment: Thanks Charleh! I also used your advice on this issue.